# "A GameObject can only contain one 'Graphic' component." problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I`m making the quiz game in Unity using C#. Each question consists two game objects: question text and question image. Here is the fragment of the script:

```
[SerializeField] Text QuestionTask;
[SerializeField] Text QuestionImage;
[SerializeField] GameObject temp;
[SerializeField] GameObject questionImagePrefab

public void LoadQuestion(Question question)
{
    CurrentQuestion = question;

    //delete possible old elements
    DeleteQuestion();
    //set question Text and Image
    QuestionTask.text = CurrentQuestion.QuestionTask;
    QuestionImage.text = CurrentQuestion.QuestionImage;
    questionImagePrefab.AddComponent(typeof(Image));
    temp = Instantiate(questionImagePrefab);
    temp.GetComponent<Image>().sprite= Resources.Load<Sprite>(QuestionImage.text);
    }
```

In runtime text is showing but image isnt. In the Inspector window I see the name of the sprite but nothing is on the game screen. After load the question I have message in console:
       "Can't add 'Image' to QuestionImagePrefab because a 'Image' is already added to the game object!
        A GameObject can only contain one 'Graphic' component."
I`ve been trying call the method:

```
     Destroy(temp);
```

but nothing. Have someone had similar issue? I have searched a lot but didn`t find any solutions. Thanks for help.

Comment: I suggest that you google the error message to look for possible solutions. I also suggest that you back up and get something simpler to work. For example, render a single, static sprite.

Comment: doesnt your imageprefab already have an image component? wouldnt you just set the image on it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like questionImagePrefab already has an `Image` component. If this is the case, you do not need to add an `Image` component to your game object (because it is already there).

I suggest you try removing the line:

```
questionImagePrefab.AddComponent(typeof(Image));
```

and post the results here.

Comment: I removed that line and message diapered but still I don`t see image on the game screen (and the sprite is in the inspector window).

Comment: Is `temp.GetComponent<Image>()` successful? Try checking for null. Also, where is the sprite showing up in the Inspector window? How about camera position? Is the sprite even in view? There is a lot more information that could make this easier to solve. I suggested editing the description to add as many details as you can. Maybe even a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

After checking different answers. This code worked for me:

```
public GameObject obj1; //your image object

void Start(){
    string path = "your path";
        Sprite img1 = LoadNewSprite( path );
        obj1.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = img1;
}


public Sprite LoadNewSprite(string FilePath, float PixelsPerUnit = 100.0f, SpriteMeshType spriteType = SpriteMeshType.Tight)
{      
    // Load a PNG or JPG image from disk to a Texture2D, assign this texture to a new sprite and return its reference
    Texture2D SpriteTexture = LoadTexture(FilePath);
    Sprite NewSprite = Sprite.Create(SpriteTexture, new Rect(0, 0, SpriteTexture.width, SpriteTexture.height), new Vector2(0, 0), PixelsPerUnit, 0, spriteType);

    return NewSprite;
}

public Texture2D LoadTexture(string FilePath)
    { 
        // Load a PNG or JPG file from disk to a Texture2D
        // Returns null if load fails
 
        Texture2D Tex2D;
        byte[] FileData;
 
        if (File.Exists(FilePath))
        {
            FileData = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
            Tex2D = new Texture2D(2, 2);           // Create new "empty" texture
            if (Tex2D.LoadImage(FileData))           // Load the imagedata into the texture (size is set automatically)
                return Tex2D;                 // If data = readable -> return texture
        }
        return null;                     // Return null if load failed
    }
```

Code based on Link source: [lnk1](https://forum.unity.com/threads/generating-sprites-dynamically-from-png-or-jpeg-files-in-c.343735/)